# error while using ngBusy module during http.post

Tags: angular

I am trying to use ngBusy module to show " loading ..." while server is doing some process. I was trying to do what is told in this [link][1].

```
import {BusyModule} from 'angular2-busy';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

Added in  the imports section in app.module.ts

In my .ts file, when I assign this.busy. I get the error : "Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Promise'.
  Property 'then' is missing in type 'Subscription'"

What is the issue here.

```
busy: Promise<any>;

 **this.busy** = this.http.post(serverUrl , formData)
        .map(
            (response: Response) => {
                this.status=  new Object(response.status, response.statusText);                   
             })
        .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
        .subscribe(
           //  data => console.log('success' +  this.loadStatus),
            // error => console.log(error)
        );
```

Comment: I fixed it.  I should use a subscription instead of promise based.